# Drawing a game tree on Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees

I need to draw the following game tree on `tikz`. It's a bayesian game.
Sorry for the pic, I made it on Paint.

So basically there are 2 players G and T, N is the nature that gives a chance for each type of player. The action of G is continuous, that's why I put the curve line.

[image]

So, my main doubr is to put the continuous set of action for player G and to put the same set of information for players of the same type. As it can be seen in the following pic: 
[image]

```
 \documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
% Two node styles for game trees: solid and hollow
solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
hollow node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,edge from parent/.style={draw,thick}]
% Two node styles: solid and hollow
\tikzstyle{solid node}=[circle,draw,inner sep=1.2,fill=black];
\tikzstyle{hollow node}=[circle,draw,inner sep=1.2];
% Specify spacing for each level of the tree
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=15mm,sibling distance=50mm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=15mm,sibling distance=25mm]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=15mm,sibling distance=15mm]
\tikzstyle{level 4}=[level distance=15mm,sibling distance=10mm]
% The Tree
\node(0)[hollow node]{}
child{node[solid node]{}
child{node[solid node]{}
child{node[below]{$1,0$} edge from parent node[left]{$\gamma$}
child{node[below]{$2,3$} edge from parent node[right]{$\tal$}
edge from parent node[above left]{$P$}
}
%I need to put for options in the node
child{node[solid node]{}
edge from parent node[above right]{$N$}
}
edge from parent node[above left]{$\theta$}
}
child{node[solid node]{}
child{node[solid node]{}
child{node[below]{$1,0$} edge from parent node(m)[left]{$\gamma$}
child{node[below]{$2,3$} edge from parent node(n)[right]{$\tal$}
edge from parent node[above left]{$c$}
}
child{node[solid node]{}
edge from parent node[above right]{$N$}
}
edge from parent node[above right]{$1-\theta$}
}
% information sets
\drawloosely dotted,very thicktoout=-15,in=195;
% movers
\node[above,yshift=2]at(0){};
\foreach \x in {1,2} \node[above,yshift=2]at(0-\x){};
\node at($.5(m)+.5(n)$){1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I tried using this code here:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{hollow node}=[circle,draw,inner sep=1.5]
\tikzstyle{solid node}=[circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black]
\tikzset{
red node/.style={circle,draw=red,fill=red,inner sep=1.2},
blue node/.style={rectangle,draw=blue,inner sep=2.5}
}
% Specify spacing for each level of the tree
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=15mm,sibling distance=40mm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=15mm,sibling distance=30mm]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=15mm,sibling distance=15mm]
\tikzstyle{level 4}=[level distance=15mm,sibling distance=12mm]

\node[hollow node,label=above:{Natureza}]{}
child{node(1)[solid node]{}
child{node[solid node]{} edge from parent node[left]{$P$}}
child{node[solid node]{} edge from parent node[right]{$N$}}
edge from parent node[left,xshift=-3]{$\theta$}
}
child{node(2)[solid node]{}
child{node[solid node]{} edge from parent node[left]{$P$}}
child{node[solid node]{} edge from parent node[right]{$N$}}
edge from parent node[right,xshift=3]{$1-\theta$}
};
\node at ($(1)!.5!(2)$) {$Governo$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If anyone could help me, I would be glad.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to do a game tree in Latex

Comment: see example on top of the page 325 in TikZ & PGF manual (v 3.0.1a). it can serve you as starting point. also see http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/

Comment: I tried using the templates on this site: https://sites.google.com/site/kochiuyu/Tikz. My problem is to set a not simetrical tree and to put information set for players of the same type in the last label.

Comment: Show us what you got with whatever you tried. Nobody wants to type out the content of your tree from an image file just in order to see if they might be able to help. There are many, many, many similar examples on this site and elsewhere and many packages to choose from.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5447/how-can-i-draw-simple-trees-in-latex?s=2|51.1636.

Comment: Similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314282/plotting-a-probability-tree-with-tikz. Very similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54308/tikz-game-tree-representation-with-continuum-of-moves. [I knew this arc thing had come up before - at least twice, I think. I didn't remember it was the 'continuous moves' representation, but a search on that would have turned up existing solutions, since the OP obviously could use that as a search term, given that's the point of the question ....]

Comment: They do not solve my doubt at all; I'll edit my question

Comment: I updated with some codes

Comment: What's the issue with the code you posted exactly? That is, what about the output isn't the way you want it? Note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

Comment: Is the problem that you get an error? (I do, but I don't know if that's the problem you're seeing.) If so, please include the text of the error message in your question. Also, if this code was written by somebody else, please note that it is only courteous to say whose it is and to provide a link. This also helps people trying to help you as they can see the original context & any explanation.

Answer (score 4):

It is not altogether clear what exactly you want changed and what exactly you are stuck on, even with the addition of code.

Personally, I would use Forest because I like it and it is easy to make it do things concisely and more-or-less automagically, depending on your requirements. You can also use Ti*k*Z code in the tree, since it is based on Ti*k*Z. Tree specifications are a lot more concise, however.

Here's an example which implements a configuration where the content specified for each node is split:

```
<label>:<edge label>
```

and the option

```
my arc
```

enables the drawing of the little green arcs. Hopefully this should get you started.

Then we can write

```
  [N, label=above:Natureza
    [G:\theta, my arc
      [N:P, name=a
        [T:\gamma[:A][:R]]
        [T:\tau[:A][:R]]
        [T:\phi[:A][:R]]
        [T:1-\gamma-\tau-\phi[:A][:R]]
      ]
      [:N, name=b]
    ]
    [G:1-\theta, my arc, before typesetting nodes={prepend'={a}, append'={b}}
    ]
  ]
```

to specify the main tree, adding the 'Governo' label by hand afterwards.

```
  \node [font=\itshape] at (!r |- !r1) {Governo};
```

The result is as follows:

[image: tree with little green arcs]

With a judicious definition for `copy name template` we can implement a style, `copy connect` to join a node to its counterpart on the other side.

Then we can write

```
  [N, label=above:Natureza
    [G:\theta, my arc
      [N:P, name=a, for children=copy connect
        [T:\gamma[:A][:R]]
        [T:\tau[:A][:R]]
        [T:\phi[:A][:R]]
        [T:1-\gamma-\tau-\phi[:A][:R]]
      ]
      [:N, name=b]
    ]
    [G:1-\theta, my arc, before typesetting nodes={prepend'={a}, append'={b}}
    ]
  ]
  \node [font=\itshape] at (!r |- !r1) {Governo};
```

to produce

[image: tree with big orange arcs, too]

This works because the nodes on the right are copies of the nodes on the left and we've labelled our copies systematically by appending `-c` to the name.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
  % Two node styles for game trees: solid and hollow
  solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
  hollow node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    l sep'+=25pt,
    s sep'+=5pt,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    where content={}{}{
      split option={content}{:}{my label,my edge label},
      delay={content=},
    },
    delay={for descendants={if n children=0{}{solid node}}},
  },
  hollow node,
  my label/.style={
    if={isodd(n)}{label={[green!75!black, font=\small]left:#1}}{label={[green!75!black, font=\small]right:#1}}
  },
  my edge label/.style={
    if={isodd(n)}{edge label={node [midway, red, left, font=\scriptsize] {$#1$}}}{edge label={node [midway, red, right, font=\scriptsize] {$#1$}}}
  },
  my arc/.style={
    tikz+={
      \draw [green!75!black] ($()!0.3!(!l)$) [bend left] to ($()!0.3!(!1) + (-5pt,2.5pt)$);
    },
  },
  copy name template={#1-c},
  copy connect/.style={
    tikz+/.process={
      Ow {name}
      {
        \draw [orange] () [bend left=15] to (##1-c);
      }%
    },
  }
  [N, label=above:Natureza
    [G:\theta, my arc
      [N:P, name=a, for children=copy connect
        [T:\gamma[:A][:R]]
        [T:\tau[:A][:R]]
        [T:\phi[:A][:R]]
        [T:1-\gamma-\tau-\phi[:A][:R]]
      ]
      [:N, name=b]
    ]
    [G:1-\theta, my arc, before typesetting nodes={prepend'={a}, append'={b}}
    ]
  ]
  \node [font=\itshape] at (!r |- !r1) {Governo};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the [`istgame`](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package:

#### Edit: istgame v2.0

With the istgame v2.0, `\istrootcntm` (instead of \istcntm) and `\xtCInfoset` (curved information set) can improve codes a little. (discouraged to use obsolete `\istcntm`)

```
\begin{document}   

\begin{istgame}[font=\scriptsize]
\xtALPush{-2pt}{-2pt}
% top part
\xtdistance{15mm}{50mm}
\istroot(0)[chance node]{N}
  \istb{\theta}[al]
  \istb{1-\theta}[ar]
  \endist
% middle part: left
\cntmdistance*{15mm}{15mm}
\istrootcntm[-120](P1)(0-1)
  \istb{P}[l]  \endist
\istroot(N1)(0-1)<135>{G}
  \istb*<grow=-60>{N}[r]
  \endist
% middle part: right
\istrootcntm[-120](P2)(0-2)
  \istb{P}[l]
  \endist
\istroot(N2)(0-2)  
  \istb*<grow=-60>{N}[r]
  \endist
% lower part: left
\xtdistance{15mm}{10mm}
\istroot(PN1)(P1-1)[chance node]<180>{N}
  \istb{\gamma}[l]
  \istb{\tau}[l]
  \istb{\phi}[l]
  \istb{1-\gamma-\tau-\phi}[r]
  \endist
% lower part: right
\xtdistance{15mm}{10mm}
\istroot(PN2)(P2-1)[chance node]<180>{N}
  \istb{\gamma}[l]
  \istb{\tau}[l]
  \istb{\phi}[l]
  \istb{1-\gamma-\tau-\phi}[r]
  \endist
% bottom part
\xtdistance{10mm}{5mm}
\foreach \a in {1,2}
  {\foreach \b in {1,2,3,4}
     {\istroot(T\a\b)(PN\a-\b)<180>{T}
      \istb{A}[l]  \istb{B}[r]  \endist
     }
  }
% information sets
\foreach \c in {1,2,3,4}
  {\xtCInfoset[solid,thin,orange](T1\c)(T2\c)<1.2>
  }
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Original answer (istgame v1.0)

```
%% full codes
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}   

\begin{istgame}[font=\scriptsize]
\xtALPush{-2pt}{-2pt}
% top part
\xtdistance{15mm}{50mm}
\istroot(0)[chance node]{N}
  \istb{\theta}[al]
  \istb{1-\theta}[ar]
  \endist
% middle part: left
\istcntm[-120](cntm)(0-1)[green]+15mm..15mm+
\istroot[-120](P1)(cntm)<135>{G}+15mm..15mm+
  \istb{P}[l]
  \endist
\istroot(N1)(cntm)  
  \istb*<grow=-60>{N}[r]
  \endist
% middle part: right
\istcntm[-120](cntm)(0-2)[green]+15mm..15mm+
\istroot[-120](P2)(cntm)<45>{G}+15mm..15mm+
  \istb{P}[l]
  \endist
\istroot(N2)(cntm)  
  \istb*<grow=-60>{N}[r]
  \endist
% lower part: left
\xtdistance{15mm}{10mm}
\istroot(PN1)(P1-1)[chance node]<180>{N}
  \istb{\gamma}[l]
  \istb{\tau}[l]
  \istb{\phi}[l]
  \istb{1-\gamma-\tau-\phi}[r]
  \endist
\xtdistance{10mm}{5mm}
\istroot(T11)(PN1-1)<180>{T}
  \istb{A}[l]  \istb{R}[r]  \endist
\istroot(T12)(PN1-2)<180>{T}
  \istb{A}[l]  \istb{R}[r]  \endist
\istroot(T13)(PN1-3)<180>{T}
  \istb{A}[l]  \istb{R}[r]  \endist
\istroot(T14)(PN1-4)<180>{T}
  \istb{A}[l]  \istb{R}[r]  \endist
% lower part: right
\xtdistance{15mm}{10mm}
\istroot(PN2)(P2-1)[chance node]<180>{N}
  \istb{\gamma}[l]
  \istb{\tau}[l]
  \istb{\phi}[l]
  \istb{1-\gamma-\tau-\phi}[r]
  \endist
\xtdistance{10mm}{5mm}
\istroot(T21)(PN2-1)<180>{T}
  \istb{A}[l]  \istb{R}[r]  \endist
\istroot(T22)(PN2-2)<180>{T}
  \istb{A}[l]  \istb{R}[r]  \endist
\istroot(T23)(PN2-3)<180>{T}
  \istb{A}[l]  \istb{R}[r]  \endist
\istroot(T24)(PN2-4)<180>{T}
  \istb{A}[l]  \istb{R}[r]  \endist
% information sets
\xtInfoset[solid,thin,orange,bend left=20](T11)(T21)
\xtInfoset[solid,thin,orange,bend left=20](T12)(T22)
\xtInfoset[solid,thin,orange,bend left=20](T13)(T23)
\xtInfoset[solid,thin,orange,bend left=20](T14)(T24)
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```

The `istgame` environment is just like the `tikzpicture` environment.
For the bottom part of this tree, you can use `\foreach` to repeat things.
A complete example is as follows:

```
%% shortened codes using \foreach
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}   

\begin{istgame}[font=\scriptsize]
\xtALPush{-2pt}{-2pt}
% top part
\xtdistance{15mm}{50mm}
\istroot(0)[chance node]{N}
  \istb{\theta}[al]
  \istb{1-\theta}[ar]
  \endist
% middle part: left
\istcntm[-120](cntm)(0-1)[green]+15mm..15mm+
\istroot[-120](P1)(cntm)<135>{G}+15mm..15mm+
  \istb{P}[l]
  \endist
\istroot(N1)(cntm)  
  \istb*<grow=-60>{N}[r]
  \endist
% middle part: right
\istcntm[-120](cntm)(0-2)[green]+15mm..15mm+
\istroot[-120](P2)(cntm)<45>{G}+15mm..15mm+
  \istb{P}[l]
  \endist
\istroot(N2)(cntm)  
  \istb*<grow=-60>{N}[r]
  \endist
% lower part: left
\xtdistance{15mm}{10mm}
\istroot(PN1)(P1-1)[chance node]<180>{N}
  \istb{\gamma}[l]
  \istb{\tau}[l]
  \istb{\phi}[l]
  \istb{1-\gamma-\tau-\phi}[r]
  \endist
% lower part: right
\xtdistance{15mm}{10mm}
\istroot(PN2)(P2-1)[chance node]<180>{N}
  \istb{\gamma}[l]
  \istb{\tau}[l]
  \istb{\phi}[l]
  \istb{1-\gamma-\tau-\phi}[r]
  \endist
% bottom part
\xtdistance{10mm}{5mm}
\foreach \a in {1,2}
  {\foreach \b in {1,2,3,4}
     {\istroot(T\a\b)(PN\a-\b)<180>{T}
      \istb{A}[l]  \istb{B}[r]  \endist
     }
  }
% information sets
\foreach \c in {1,2,3,4}
  {\xtInfoset[solid,thin,orange,bend left=20](T1\c)(T2\c)
  }
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Neat. I do not find this in Ubuntu's texlive set, otherwise I'd put it to use.

Comment: Ubuntu is probably installing an outdated TeXLive and the package is quite new. You can install it into your local `texmf` folder from the version on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame).